# JQuery - hotkeys with multiple bind calls

Tags: jquery-plugins

Requirement is, in a screen we need to have hotkey for "ctrl+1, Ctrl+2 & ctrl+3". Using hotkeys plugin [http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/], , I'm having some problems with the following code, in browser if i open this below page and if i press 'ctrl+1' alert message is coming twice where as expected result is we should only get "You found the hotkey ctrl+1!" alert once. I am new to JQuery world so i am not sure weather i am missing some thing or plugin it self got some known issue.

Could some one comment on the issue.

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Hotkeys</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+1', function() {
   alert('You found the hotkey ctrl+1!');
});

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+2', function() {
   alert('You found the hotkey ctrl+2!');
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
HOYKEY DEMO : Press 'Ctrl+1/Ctrl+2'
</body>
</html>
```

---

Thanks,
~Ram

Answer (score 2):

Try using this newer version...

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

I found it resolved your issue.  I ran into an issue using 0.7.9 after using jQuery 1.6+.  In that case, I use fancybox and all the fancybox javascript stopped working.  After switching out for hotkeys .8, all my issues went away.  I do believe there is a newer version of hotkeys currently under development but haven't found the source yet.  If you were to end up using fancybox, lets just say this tip saved you a few hours :)